# Запрет индексации в robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Есть на сайте php файлик (`site.ru/no.php`), который выводит данные, которые не нужно индексировать.

Файлик работает так: **`no.php?id=100`**, то есть выводит определённую инфу через `GET`.

Вопрос: если в robots.txt прописать **`Disallow: /no.php`**, то содержимое даже при гет запросах поисковые роботы точно не будут индексировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disallow: /no.php` [блокирует доступ к страницам](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml#allow-disallow) начинающимся с `/no.php`, т.е. не будет

Другой пример:

```
Disallow: /page?*param= 
# блокирует доступ к страницам page с GET параметром param
```

Answer (score 1):

Файл `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /no.php
Disallow: /no.php*?
```

Результат проверки **[Яндекс.Вебмастер](http://webmaster.yandex.ru/robots.xml)**:

`/no.php            запрещен правилом /no.php`
`/no.php?id=1       запрещен правилом /no.php*?*`